# mysql: design practices

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have tables setup as such:
A message is sent out to a group of users.

This message is put in the `parent_message` table
This table contains `id | sender_id | date`

each message that is sent in that group is put in the `child_message` table
this table contains `id | parent_id | message | date_sent`

when a reply is received it is put into the `reply_message` table
this table contains `id | child_id | message | date_received`.

Now I have a few questions about this setup.

---

1) Every time the page is loaded I need to show how many child messages each parent message has.
Would you add a column to the parent_message table called child_count or work it out in your query.
why, why not?

*Example query*

```
select *, 
count(select parent_id from child_message c where c.parent_id = p.parent_id ) child_count 
from parent_message;
```

2) If the user chooses they can view all reply messages to a parent message.
would you add the parent_id to the reply reply_message table or work it out in your query?
Why, why not?

*Example query*

```
select * from reply_message 
where child_id in(select id from child_message where parent_id = '66')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it very much depends on the amount of messages. If you have like a million messages in the system, a join to child_message can become very expensive. In that case adding a child_count to the parent table can be beneficial for your performance. Same goes for your second use case. Of course that is some de-normalization of your data, so if your system allows for reshaping topics and replies (like splitting a topic) you have to do additional bookkeeping in that case.

Another approach would be creating index tables, which hold the information you need and update them offline in an asynchronous way, if you don't need the information to be 100% accurate all the time e.g.

table message_counts (parent_id, child_count)

And then schedule updates on these when a new message is added to the system, e.g. by using a trigger.

So bottom line, unless you encounter performance issues, keep your tables normalized, just like they are. When you expect millions of messages and replies, some de-normalization can help speed up things. Index tables can help creating aggregated statistics offline, unless you need them to be accurate and up-to-date.

Comment: Hmm,

Interesting thoughts on the aggregate stat tables.

Will have to think about that.

The system has no futher manipulation on the messages so this is fine.

You have basically covered my question in one line, Do I choose normalization or performance, the tables themselves can get very big, as one parent message will have approx 15k child messages, So what would your suggestion be?

Comment: I'd definitely go for denormalization then. Just think if you have like 1000 parents with 15000 childs each, it would be a joined table of 15m lines from which to extract the aggregates. Doing this realtime is not feasible. If you use triggers to update the child count when a new child is inserted, then you don't even lose consistency. On the other hand this will create an exclusive lock on the parent line while a child is written, so if you have a lot of writes compared to your reads, the aggregate tables might be an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off working it out in both cases but I would rewrite the queries

```
SELECT 
   p.*
   count(child.*) childCount
FROM 
   parent_message p
   LEFT JOIN  child_message  c
   on c.parent_id = p.parent_id
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       rm.*
    FROM 
        reply_message rm
        INNER JOIN child_message  cm
        rm.child_id = cm.id 
   WHERE
       parent_id = '66'
```

I also would list the fields instead of doing the `SELECT *`

Comment: Thankyou for this, I did not even think about joining them properly, as for the select *, thats more to shorten the query, I dont actually use that :)